# Insert multiple keywords in one field

Tags: python, django

My question is how i can insert multiple keywords in one django field and show them in a template like stackoverflow tags.

Models:

```
class Jobs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, default='')
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = ?????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another class and use many-to-many relationship between jobs class (tags) and new class:

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    tag_name=models.CharField()
```

In jobs class

```
 tags=models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
```

For show in template you can use for loop, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make it a Comma separated value.

```
class Jobs(models.Model):
    tags = models.TextField()

    def tag_list(self):
        return self.tags.split(",")

    def add_tag(self, tag_str):
        current_tags = self.tag_list()
        current_tags.append(tag_str)
        current_tags = set(current_tags)
        new_tag_string = ",".join(current_tags)
        self.tags = new_tag_string
        # you could save the model now or let caller save it outside of this method. I suggest letting caller save the model.

    def remove_tag(self, tag_str):
        current_tags = self.tag_list()
        current_tags.remove(tag_str)
        new_tag_string = ",".join(current_tags)
        self.tags = new_tag_string
        # you could save the model now or let caller save it outside of this method. I suggest letting caller save the model.
```